# Android Studio E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class '.DatabaseHelper', referenced from method .DatabaseManager

Tags: android, android-studio, ormlite

Hello I'm getting this error using Android Studio on runtime but only on devices with an SDK version <= 19. Everything compiles ok but I get this error on my databaseHelper Class.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
}
```

My databaseHelper class extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`
Everything was working fine while my compileSdkVersion was at 19
Here is what I updated:

- gradle: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'` > 1.3.0
- sdk Version: `compileSdkVersion 19` > 23
- appcompat: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1` > 23
- play-services

My databaseHelper Class is in the same package than other Classes which work fine !

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm still trying to find out what cuase it

Comment: BTW i have noticed that every place were i create Anonymous Classes i get the E/dalvikvm: Could not find class error on the logcat. If you remove the anonymous class creation it seems to work. but the WIERD thing is this used to work, and still work on API greater than 19

Comment: Anyone got solution for this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 11):

As you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle. Make sure your application class is extending [`MultiDexApplication`](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) instead of the `Application` class.

Alternatively, as suggested in the docs, you can add the following method to your application class.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me. I changed Application to MultiDexApplication

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. `multiDex` is not supported correctly prior to lollypop. Once I removed the additional libraries and remove `multidex` setting on Gradle everything started to work fine.

remove.

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time a, try to turn off ProGuard

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: Thank you but It's still the same ;(