# Android JSoup classes not found in emulator when deployed with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have a program which uses Jsoup.connect. On a real device (e.g. Samsung galaxy S5)my program just works fine. But when I deploy the package using Android Studio on any Emulator (Bluestacks or Genymotion) I get the following error:

```
03-13 16:50:57.619 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-13 16:50:57.619 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19130: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-13 16:50:57.619 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19134: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.639 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 64487: Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;.select (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/select/Elements;
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner', referenced from method org.jsoup.Jsoup.clean
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8273 (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Cleaner;) in Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner', referenced from method org.jsoup.Jsoup.clean
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8273 (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Cleaner;) in Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)
03-13 16:50:57.647 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)
03-13 16:50:57.651 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.651 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.651 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.651 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner', referenced from method org.jsoup.Jsoup.isValid
03-13 16:50:57.651 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8273 (Lorg/jsoup/safety/Cleaner;) in Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.655 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.659 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.659 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 64535: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 64535: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 64537: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.parseInput (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document; (8264)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;' failed
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;)
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 64536: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.parseBodyFragment (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;
03-13 16:50:57.663 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 64536: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.parseBodyFragment (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Document;
03-13 16:50:57.699 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 64534: Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;.htmlParser ()Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;
03-13 16:50:57.707 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.707 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.707 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.707 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/jsoup/parser/Parser;)
03-13 16:50:57.711 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d82b20)
03-13 16:50:57.711 11841-11841/nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2, PID: 11841
                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.parser.Parser
                                                                                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:371)
                                                                                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:352)
                                                                                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:64)
                                                                                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:37)
                                                                                  at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
                                                                                  at nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2.util.NetworkUtil.checkAppVersion(NetworkUtil.java:278)
                                                                                  at nl.linnaeus.floron.plantobs2.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:25)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems that somehow the jsoup jar is not found. In my graddle config if have the following dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    // own extra  libraries
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jdom-2.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/sanselan-0.97-incubator.jar')
```

Comment: Do you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle ? What Android version is the emulator running ? If I remember right, Multidex does not work correctly on android pre-5.0. But check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697460/android-studio-e-dalvikvm-could-not-find-class-databasehelper-referenced-fr).

Comment: @JonasCz Yes multiDexEnables is set to true. But your hint was great. It now works, However, I do not understand why jsoup is causing the problem.